# Unable to Load GloVIS using Java 8 due to Security Requirement (Windows 8, Java 8 v.40)

Tags: java

After migrating to a new PC running Windows 8.1 (64-bit), and updating to the most recent Java 8 version (update 40), I am unable to load the GloVis website (http://glovis.usgs.gov/); every time it reports a security error and says may not load due to the risk the plug-in poses.

I have tried, not in this exact order:

1. Updating Java
2. Changing security settings from 'Medium-High' to 'Medium'
3. Restarting computer / browser / site
4. Installing 32- and 64-bit versions of Java
5. Adding the website to site exception list

The GloVis instructions just say upgrade to the most recent Java version, which I have already done. When I access on another, older computer everything seems to run just fine.

Has anyone had this experience and been able to access GloVis using Java 8?

[image: Error message pop-up]

Comment: Can't say about Windows 8 but works for me with Windows 7, Firefox 36.0.1 and Java Plug-in 11.40.2 for Mozilla browsers (Java(TM) Platform SE 8 U40).

Comment: Okay, thank you for info. I can also get this to run on another computer, running a different operating system, so unable to confirm if it is a Windows security setting unique to Windows8, my computer, or another unrelated issue manifesting. I haven't gone through all the steps listed here, but it looks like changing deployment java settings may do the trick: https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/entry/introducing_deployment_rule_sets